# Maximum and minimum value for height and width on iframe

Tags: css, iframe, maxlength

Been doing media Queries for Iframe. This two media queries below works fine for iframe when editing the Height and width

```
min-device-width: 768px) and(max-device-width: 1024px) 
min-device-width: 600px) and (max-device-width: 960px)
```

However when queries on htc phone it does not do anything with its size..
min-device-width: 360px)and (max-device-width: 640px)

Here is my code

```
@media screen and (min-width: 360px) and (max-width: 640px),(min-device-width: 360px)and
(max-device-width: 640px) and (orientation : landscape)
 {
    /* CSS */

    .wrap{
        width:75%;
    }
    .iframe {
    max-height:30vh;
    max-width:30%;
    }
    .html{

        background-color:red;
    }


}
```

even the background colors not working when try to do a troubleshooting

Comment: `device-width` and `device-height` have been depreciated. [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries]

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to the device high-resolution, and thus queries never get triggered. Try specifying the [resolution units on your media queries](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/).

Otherwise just use `min-height` and `min-width` media queries. They're more reliable.

Comment: For the min height and width not work ..How can i know the size of the screen using the link you provided..if i want to use for min-width 360px and max-width 640px?

Comment: Hit this page with your device: http://www.whatismyscreenresolution.com/ to know the device CSS pixel resolution. Then for testing purposes use the simple `min-height` and `min-width` media queries.

Comment: This is i used still have no effect.. .iframe {
 min-height:30vh;
 min-width:55%;
 
    }

Comment: I meant media queries. Try something simple like the following and post your example on codepen.io.
`@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) { ... }`

Comment: I've tried  but it overwrites other media queries so i change it back

Comment: The point is to see if it works. If so, then it's a matter of tweaking all other media queries and make sure they don't conflict with each other. (upvote answer & comments for further assistance)